# distinguish whether app was launched through the UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am working on a alarm clock app and I've been stuck for the last couple of days. I was hoping you guys could help out.

My question is;

Is there any way to distinguish whether the app was opened through the UILocalNotification alertAction or just opened regularly?

I want to use the UILocalNotification to create a snooze feature, so if the app is opened by the user tapping on the action button on the LocalNotification, a snooze mechanism will launch (but obviously i don't want that to launch if the user regularly opens the app to set the time or something)

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible as described in the [UILocalNotifaction class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> In the
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
>   method the application delegate can
>   obtain the `UILocalNotification` object
>   from the passed-in options dictionary...

Therefore you can check the options dictionary to see if the notification is present. If it is then that's how the app was launched.

Comment: Thanks! If I'm interpreting that right, in the ViewController.m I can ask the passed-in options dictionary with the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey to see if it has the notification, right? Thank you:)

Comment: Nearly. This method is defined in the the YourAppNameAppDelegate.m file so you will get the dictionary and perform the check there. You could do something like add a boolean property to the app delegate which the view can check to see how it was launched.